# How to Push an UIViewController with NIB file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, push, nib

I'm new to iOS development and I'm having a big headache not understanding something that may be pretty easy. 
Basically I'm using a UITableViewController to go to another UITableViewController, but then I need to go from that second UITableViewController to a UIViewController. I want this UIViewController to have a .xib file for me to make a quick UI but I can't seem to find the way to push from the Second UITableViewController to this UIViewController. 
I managed to programatically show a label, but not a UI from a .xib.

This is the code that works with the programmatic label:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.detailController.title = @"Disclosure Button Pressed";
    NSString *selectedMovie = self.movies[indexPath.row];
    NSString *detailMessage = [[NSString alloc]
                                initWithFormat:@"This is details for %@.",
                                selectedMovie];
    self.detailController.message = detailMessage;
    self.detailController.title = selectedMovie;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailController
                                        animated:YES];
}
```

And this is the .m of the UIViewController that works to show a UILabel programatically.

```
@implementation BIDDisclosureDetailViewController
- (UILabel *)label;
{
    return (id)self.view;
}
- (void)loadView;
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.view = label;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.label.text = self.message;
}
@end
```

Basically I don't want to create any UIObject Programatically, I need a .xib to create the UI.

Thanks

(iOS 6, not using storyboards)

Comment: Where are you creating the actual view controller? You need to alloc init it before you push it.

Comment: If you're using iOS 6, why use xibs instead of a storyboard? I can see no reason to use xibs any more unless you're dealing with legacy code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Loading up a `UIViewController` from a xib is easy. When your tableview delegate sends the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message you can load up a xib and present the view controller as follows:

```
BIDDisclosureDetailViewController *controller = [[BIDDisclosureDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BIDDisclosureDetailView" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Some things to note:

1. You don't load up a view controller from a xib, only a view. Which is why in the code above I am creating a new instance of the view controller by using `initWithNibName:bundle:`
2. In order for all of this to get hooked up properly in IB, you set the "File's Owner" in the xib to be of the correct view controller type (BIDDisclosureDetailViewController).
3. Make sure to remove the `loadView` code you have in there as well, it will mess things up when trying to use the xib.

**Side note!** you should not have semi-colons at the end of method signatures like this one:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

It is considered bad form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, (I was missing the initWithNibName)  now I wonder if there is a way to open a viewcontroller instead a view. I would like to use the split view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ViewControllerToBePushed *viewController = [[ViewControllerToBePushed alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerToBePushed" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Use the above method to push to view controller when a particular row is selected